# Api call to .net C sharp web api project fails in swift but works fine

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using a asp.net back end with a login end point but no matter what I DO in the swift version of this code I get a 415 when I use it in .net and sharp the api works am not sure what am doing wrong here.

And yes I have enabled transport protocol but its not decoding the jwt token correctly for me in swift

Basically the end point returns the jet token used for accessing the api in an object

```
let jwtAccessToken: String = "" 
let urlString = "http://url.com/login" *** hidden for security 
                purposes but is correct ****


func CallWebApi()
{
    // create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: urlString)! // change server url accordingly
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [ "username": 
     "user1@domain.com", "password": "pass1"]

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
     forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "Post"

    
    do {
     request.httpBody =  try    
    JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
      }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
      data, response, error in
        guard
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            error == nil
        else {           

           // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error", error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
            return
        }
        
        guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {    
              // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            return
        }
        
        // do whatever you want with the `data`, e.g.:
        
        do {
            let responseObject = data
            print(responseObject)
        } catch {
            print(error) 
          // parsing error
            
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            } else {
                print("unable to parse response as string")
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
    
}
```

MyModel is basically a string

```
 import Foundation
 class AuthenticationResponse: ObservableObject {

 @Published var jwtToken: String


init(jwtToken: String) {
    self.jwtToken = jwtToken

 }

}
```

I think 20 years of c sharp  in not helping and am doing things it way and not the swift way if someone could advice be great.

Also in csharp we were told its not great in keeping alive the http client as can degrade performance is this the same for swift and if any library's you can recommend makes the code a bit neater the api has swagger docs enabled.

**Edit 3**

Example response expected back

```
{
   "id": "b181104e-ba3e-4dba-b124-4bb4a3873b17",
   "firstName": "user1",
   "lastName": "lastname",
   "username": "user1lastname@domainname.com",
   "playerId": 0,
   "jwtToken":   "token in is here",//hidden for security
  "error": {
  "eventName": null,
  "errorMessage": null,
  "errorDate": null,
  "statusCode": null,
  "json": null
 },
"refreshToken": null
}
```

I typically send this to the end point from C sharp

```
{
  "username": "user1@domain.com",
  "password": "pass1"
}
```

Comment: That's strange, you are setting `Content-Type` twice, only the last one is kept (and since you send JSON in body, it seems fine, but that's still strange). `.prettyPrinted` in  `httpBody`? I'd remove it, usually it's not needed (and could be interpreted as an issue by your server, even if I don't think so).

Comment: Sorry a prity print ?

Comment: `request.httpMethod = "Post"`, try changing to `request.httpMethod = "POST"`

Comment: `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)`: `.prettyPrinted` here. And concerning the Content-Type, what's the real content-type accepted by the API?

Comment: Raw Jason @Larme

Comment: please see edit 3 I show my json I send and the response expected back @Larme

Answer (score 0):

What I found I had to do was this

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let responseObject =  try 
             decoder.decode(AuthenticationResponse.self, from: data)
            print(responseObject)
```

And change my class to be off this

```
import Foundation
struct AuthenticationResponse: Codable {

  var jwtToken: String

}
```

After I done that I got the expected string back but my question is how does one get this to run correctly its completing before I think I need await but also where is it best to stored the jwttoken?

Comment: Wait a minute. You got a 415 on the call, and you are saying that this fix, which is on the decoding in case of a success 200 is fixing the 401? How so? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: It worked I don't no why but it did the 415 could have been something else mind u